# Modify dataframe during iterrows inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two very similar iterrows loops, one works as I expect, the other does not. My question is what makes the second one different from the first, and why does this change the behavior of my loop? Thank you

## The working loop

I am working with a column called `date_of_birth` within the dataframe `drugs_tall`. The values in `date_of_birth` look like this:

```
> list(drugs_tall.loc[0:5,'date_of_birth'])

['10271964', '08161951', '08241965', '01211959', '12061956', '10041987']
```

I alter that column as such:

```
import numpy as np


for index, row in drugs_tall.iterrows():
    date_string = row['date_of_birth']
    print(date_string)
    if pd.isnull(row['date_of_birth']) == False:
        month_day, year = re.findall('....', date_string)
        month, day = re.findall('..', month_day)
        format_date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day
        run_date = datetime.strptime(format_date, '%Y-%m-%d')           
        row['date_of_birth'] = run_date
    else:
        row['date_of_birth'] = np.nan
```

After running the above I check the values of `date_of_birth`:

```
> list(drugs_tall.loc[0:5,'date_of_birth'])

[datetime.datetime(1964, 10, 27, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1951, 8, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1965, 8, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1959, 1, 21, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1956, 12, 6, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1987, 10, 4, 0, 0)]
```

We can see that my dates are now `datetime` objects, great!

## The non-working loop

This time I am working with three columns within a dataframe called `drugs_merged`

- An initial date: `date_of_visit`
- A number of days I want to subtract from the initial date: `diff_from_baseline_days`
- The result of the subtraction: `format_start_date`

Checking those out . . .

```
> list(drugs_merged.loc[21:25,'date_of_visit'])

[Timestamp('2011-10-12 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2011-10-13 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2011-10-13 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2011-10-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2011-10-24 00:00:00')]


> list(drugs_merged.loc[21:25,'diff_from_baseline_days'])

[42, 60.84, '', '', 182.52]

> list(drugs_merged.loc[21:25,'format_start_date'])

['',
 '',
 datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2004, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 '']
```

I now attempt to alter `format_start_date` when it is `''` and the other two columns of interest are not `''`.

```
from datetime import timedelta

#drugs_merged['placeholder'] = ""
for index, row in drugs_merged.iterrows():
    if ((row['date_of_visit'] != "") & (row['diff_from_baseline_days'] != "") & (row['format_start_date'] == "") ):
        patient = row['visit_id']
        #print(patient)
        delta = pd.Timedelta(row['diff_from_baseline_days'], unit = 'd')
        print(delta)
        date = row['date_of_visit']
        print(date)
        start_date = date - delta
        print(start_date)
        row['format_start_date'] = start_date
        print(row['format_start_date'])
```

The result of my debugging print statement for row 21 (`drugs_merged.loc[21,'diff_from_baseline_days']` from above) is:

```
42 days 00:00:00
2011-10-12 00:00:00
2011-08-31 00:00:00
2011-08-31 00:00:00
```

So we can see that the calculations are happening correctly.

Checking if `format_start_date` has been filled in the original `drugs_merged` we can see that `format_start_date` has not been changed!

```
> list(drugs_merged.loc[21:25,'format_start_date'])

['',
 '',
 datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2004, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 '']
```

To repeat my question now that you have made it the bottom of this wall of text  ... what makes the second one different from the first, and why does this change the behavior of my loop?

Thank you again

Comment: I kinda started dozing off after reading through half of this ... you need to cut the question down to its minimal elements. Try to see which parts of your code are unnecessary to replicate your error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs for `df.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> 2. You should **never modify** something you are iterating over.
>      This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the
>      data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing
>      to it will have no effect.

Thus, you should never rely on modifying `row` to affect `df`. It worked in the first case because `row` happened to be a view of `df` there, but it did not work in the second case because `row` turned out to be a copy. The Pandas API does specify when `df.iterrows` will return views or copies, so you should never rely on `row`s being a view.

We'll need to find a different way to write the code. In fact, since `iterrows` is amongst the slowest ways to manipulate a Pandas DataFrame (since it ignores Pandas' main weapon in the fight for better performance -- column-wise vectorized calculations) we should be extra-motivated to find a different way.

Happily, the loop can be vectorized:

```
mask = ((drugs_merged['date_of_visit'] != "") 
        & (drugs_merged['diff_from_baseline_days'] != "") 
        & (drugs_merged['format_start_date'] == "") )

patients = drugs_merged['visit_id']
deltas = pd.to_timedelta(drugs_merged['diff_from_baseline_days'], unit='d')
dates = drugs_merged['date_of_visit']
start_dates = dates - deltas
drugs_merged.loc[mask, 'format_start_date'] = start_dates
```

Note that you could alternatively, mask each step of the calculation (instead of only masking the final assignment):

```
mask = ((drugs_merged['date_of_visit'] != "") 
        & (drugs_merged['diff_from_baseline_days'] != "") 
        & (drugs_merged['format_start_date'] == "") )

patients = drugs_merged.loc[mask, 'visit_id']
deltas = pd.to_timedelta(drugs_merged.loc[mask, 'diff_from_baseline_days'], unit='d')
dates = drugs_merged.loc[mask, 'date_of_visit']
start_dates = dates - deltas
drugs_merged.loc[mask, 'format_start_date'] = start_dates
```

This may or may not be faster depending on the ratio of True/False values in `mask`.
Each `df.loc[mask, ...]` generates a *copy* of a portion of `df`. Copying can be an expensive operation. If `mask` is composed of 99% `True`s, then a lot of time will be wasted copying portions of `drugs_merged` for the very small advantage of avoiding computation on the `False` parts. On the other hand, if `mask` is composed of 1% `True`s, then a little copying will help avoid unnecessary computation on lots of `False` parts.

So whether it is advantageous to use the unmasked version (first block of code) or the fully masked version (second block) depends on the nature of `mask`.

---

Here is a toy example which demonstrates the problem (and the various behavior
you are seeing):

When all the values in the DataFrame are strings, the dtype is homogenous. The underlying data reside in a single NumPy array of the same homogenous dtype and which can be sliced into rows which are views. Hence, the `row`s are views:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([('X','2018-7-26','fail'),
                    ('Y','','fail')], columns=list('ABC'))
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    row['C'] = 'success'
print(df1)
```

yields

```
   A          B        C
0  X  2018-7-26  success
1  Y             success
```

When we use `pd.to_datetime` to convert the date strings into Timestamps, the dtype of one column changes from `object` to `datetime64[ns]`. Now the underlying data reside in at least two blocks -- one with dtype `object` and another with dtype `datetime64[ns]`. (Blocks can only have a single dtype. Depending on the operations you perform on a DataFrame, an "unconsolidated" DataFrame may wind up with two blocks of the same dtype. In this strange corner case, even when a DataFrame has homogenous dtype, the `row`s my still wind up being copies...). Now generating `row`s requires copying the underlying data into a new Series of dtype `object`. Since `row` is now a copy, modifying `row` fails to modify `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([('X','2018-7-26','fail'),
                    ('Y','','fail')], columns=list('ABC'))
df2['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['B'])
for idx, row in df2.iterrows():
    row['C'] = 'success'
print(df2)
```

yields

```
   A          B     C
0  X 2018-07-26  fail
1  Y        NaT  fail
```

But if we were to keep `df3` of homogenous dtype (e.g. all strings), then `row` is a view, and so modification of `row` inside the loop modifies `df3` as well:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([('X','2018-7-26','fail'),
                    ('Y','','fail')], columns=list('ABC'))
for idx, row in df3.iterrows():
    row['B'] = pd.Timestamp(row['B'])
    row['C'] = 'success'
print(df3)
```

yields

```
   A                    B        C
0  X  2018-07-26 00:00:00  success
1  Y                  NaT  success
```

Comment: How did you know that the second loop was a copy? Could you tell from the way the code is written, or is that an Occam's razor educated guess from someone who has seen this before?

Comment: It was a guess based on the symptom you described. If `row` does not modify `df`, it's probably because it is a copy.

Comment: So in my (worse :) ) answer below I say that I incorrectly changed the entire column to a datetime using `drugs_merged['date_of_visit'] = pd.to_datetime(drugs_merged['date_of_visit'])`. This made it so that when I did `drugs_merged.dtypes` not all of the columns were of type `object`. In the working loop (the one on `drugs_tall`) all of the columns were of type `object`. Is this why the second loop (where not all columns were `object`) returned a copy?

Comment: I believe there is a greater chance that `row` will be a copy when `df.dtype` is non-homogenous. Moreover, I do suspect the change of dtype or the modification of the internal blocks holding the underlying data in `drugs_merged` is the cause of the observed change in `row` from view to copy. But I haven't managed to construct a simple example to demonstrate this.

Comment: Small pointer, you can use `df['col'].astype(bool)` to check for empty strings. While not as explicit, it's in line with Python philosophy (e.g. check an empty string via `if my_string: ...`), and more efficient. Even better, you could compare `df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].values.astype(bool)` to a single Boolean array.

Comment: Incredible toy problem, I wish I could upvote you again!

Answer (score 1):

**The selected answer is best. Check out the toy example in that answer and the comments below it to understand why the below works, but should not be used.**

So in order to do the date math in the non-operative loop I had previously converted `drugs_merged['date_of_visit']` to a `datetime` object as such:

```
drugs_merged['date_of_visit'] = pd.to_datetime(drugs_merged['date_of_visit'])
```

Doing this during iteration rather than before fixed the problem:

```
from datetime import timedelta

for index, row in drugs_merged.iterrows():
    if ((row['date_of_visit'] != "") & (row['diff_from_baseline_days'] != "") & (row['format_start_date'] == "") ):
        patient = row['visit_id']
        print(patient)
        delta = pd.Timedelta(row['diff_from_baseline_days'], unit = 'd')
        print(delta)
        date = row['date_of_visit']
        print(date)

        #This is is the change
        start_date = pd.to_datetime(date) - delta
        #End change

        print(start_date)
        row['format_start_date'] = start_date
        print(row['format_start_date'])
```